# bash zip omit files

Tags: bash, unix, zip

I'd like to zip a folder, but zip skips files.
Folder structure is:

> ```
> main_folder > sub_folder > file2.sql
>               file11.txt  
>               file12.sql
> ```

Main_folder contains sub_folder and two files, subfolder contains one file.

When i use

> zip -r $path *

i receive .zip file which contains everything except file11.txt. I tried various options but have not solved the problem. Zip makes correct structure and takes every single file except files from main_folder.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
zip -r your.zip * -x file11.txt
```

man zip;

> -x files
>
> --exclude files
>
> Explicitly exclude the specified files..